# The link between the law group of an elliptic curve and coordinates

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

Let $L$ be a subfield of the algebraically closed field $K$, let $D$ ⊂ $\mathbb{P}_K^2$  be  an  elliptic  curve defined by a polynomial equation with    coefficients in $L$, and let $E$ $\in D_L$,  where  $D_L$   denote  the  set  of  points of  $D$   with  coordinates in   $L$.

Prove that $D_L$ is a subgroup in the group defined on $D$, with $E$ the zero element.

I  know  the geometric  meaning of  the  low  group  defined  on  $D$.  I   don't  know   what  is  the  link   between low  group  and  coordinates.

Comment: If you consider the "geometric construction" of the group law, then you can compute explicitly formulas for $P+Q$ and for $-P$. Since $E$ is defined over $L$, these will be rational functions with coefficients in $L$.

Comment: @Watson How  can  I  compute  explicitly formulas for  $P + Q$  and  $-P$? My definition for an elliptic curve is: a projective, plane, cubic, smooth curve.

Comment: What is your definition of $P+Q$ ? Through the Picard group?

Comment: @Watson For $P$ and $Q$ on the elliptic curve, first I consider the intersection of the line $PQ$ with  curve.  I denote this point with $P*Q$. Now I consider the intersection of the line $E(P*Q)$ with curve. This point is $P+Q$.

Comment: Well, you probably know how to write the equation of the line $PQ$, and you can find the coordinates of its intersection with $E$. Then you'll find the coordinates of $P*Q$. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: @Watson I don't work with Weirstrass form.

Comment: At least you are given a cubic curve. Maybe with Riemann-Roch theorem you can get the Weierstrass equations (which simplifies in characteristic $p \neq 2, 3$).

Comment: You are being unreasonably timid in the face of pencil-and-paper computation. I assure you that with the (nonsingular) cubic plane curve in hand, it is easy to compute the sum of $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$, two points on the curve.

Comment: @Lubin I haven't  an equation of curve.

Comment: Well, I just don’t understand, then. If you have a “a projective, plane, cubic, smooth curve”, what are you in the position of knowing about it beyond those words?